# how to copy a range of cells(n cells) from a column in one sheet and paste it, with a blank cell inserted after every 7(n cells), to another sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

how to copy a range of cells(N cells) from a column in one sheet and paste it, with a blank cell inserted after every 7(n cells), to another sheet?
Ex: Given image below

[image]

Comment: Please post the case you're seeking help for. Please add what you have tried. This link should help- https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: is this a school assignment ? ..... it is not clear what you are asking ... what does this mean ? `loop till end of cell`  and what does this mean? `7(n values)`

Comment: its just copy and paste of 7 cells each time of single column data of 100 cells to another sheet with vba, Hope you get it.

Comment: Break it into steps. Are you working with 100 cells in total in one column in the first sheet? Are you then looping each cell OR every 7 cell? Do only 7 cells in total get copied to the other sheet? Where in the other sheet is data pasted? Etc. This is the sort of information we need.  Can you show with images what you are trying to achieve? As it stands, there are too many assumptions that must be made to make this, in my opinion, a useful question.

Comment: Answering to you question:
1. Take example of 100 cells in one column in first sheet
2. Looping every 7 cells and pasting in on other sheet by creating blank cell for every 7 cells, shown in the image 
3. Data to be pasted in the cells a2, a3, a4...goes on.
Added image, please check n help on this.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: The image really helped. You could have re-phrased the question as something like: how to copy a range of cells from a column in one sheet and paste it, with a blank cell inserted after every 7|n cells, to another sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a pretty easy task and you are making it sound difficult. Here's the code to help you out.

```
Sub do_something()
    last_row = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row

   j = 1
   For i = 1 To last_row

      If i Mod 8 = 0 Then
         j = j + 1
      End If
      Cells(j, 2).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value
      j = j + 1

   Next i
End Sub
```

And as you mentioned in your comment, below code will satisfy your need.

```
Sub do_something2()
   last_row = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
   j = 1
   i = 1
   Do While i <= last_row
       Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, 1), 
       Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(j + 6, 1)).Value = _
       Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1), 
       Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + 6, 1)).Value

   j = j + 8
   i = i + 7
   Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry Dubey, Actually I was expecting to copy 7 cells each time but in the above code it copy only 1 cell each time and the values need to be pasted in other sheet.

Comment: @ShakeerSheik You never mentioned about copying 7 values in every single iteration. Anyways I have updated the answer for you. Hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent Dubey, It helped me. Thank you very much.. :)

Comment: @ShakeerSheik Your welcome. Please accept the answer to make it suitable for others also. :)